# Request/Response with multiple Consumers leads to a _skipped queue

Tags: c#, masstransit

Consider that I'm doing a Request and there are two Consumer instances that receive the same request at the same time.

The first Consumer works well and responds back to the Requestor. The second Consumer is also processing the request but when responding it creates a ..._skipped queue and writes a message there with the reason: `dead-letter`. I think this is normal behaviour because the request already got a response.

But what I want to accomplish is to avoid that the 2nd, 3rd, ... Consumers are written to the _skipped queue. The fact that a request is processed by the two Consumers is what I want to achieve, and I also want to receive response from both of them.

See the code below:

Request:

```
BusControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(busFactoryConfig =>
{
    busFactoryConfig.Host(new Uri(ServerUrl), hostConfig =>
    {
        hostConfig.Username("guest");
        hostConfig.Password("guest");
    });

    busFactoryConfig.AutoDelete = true;
    busFactoryConfig.Durable = true;
}); 

var requestClient = BusControl.CreatePublishRequestClient<IRequest, IResponse>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Response (as Queue I have a random Guid, this leads to multiple consumers consuming the same request)

```
BusControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(busFactoryConfig =>
{
    IRabbitMqHost rabbitMqHost = busFactoryConfig.Host(new Uri(ServerUrl), hostConfig =>
    {
        hostConfig.Username("guest");
        hostConfig.Password("guest");
    });

    busFactoryConfig.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitMqHost, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), receiveEndpointConfig =>
    {
        receiveEndpointConfig.Consumer<TConsumer>();
        receiveEndpointConfig.AutoDelete = true;
        receiveEndpointConfig.PurgeOnStartup = false;
        receiveEndpointConfig.Durable = true;
    });
});
```

Consumer:

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRequest> context)
{
   return context.RespondAsync("");
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer not to use the publish request client. If you know who should handle the request - use their address. Publish request serves the convenience purpose for you not to care about the receiver address but you should care you only have one service that consumes the request. You can't have the cake and eat it as too.

Comment: You are right, but we are building a 'stateless' situation where the first request is to check which server (Consumer) is busy doing some processing. And secondly, we can do a request to the specific Consumer.

Comment: Looks like a saga candidate to me.